# How to properly use shmget & shmat for IPC Shared Memory use case

Tags: c, memory, ipc, shared

I tried understand the behavior of the following code

```
int memoryId = shmget(1234, 10240, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
client *client1 = shmat(memoryId, NULL, 0);
bool *game = shmat(memoryId, NULL, 0);
*game = true;
printf("1Game: %s\n",(*game)?"true":"false");
printf("2Game: %s\n",(*game)?"true":"false");
*client1 = (client){ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, false};
printf("3Game: %s\n",(*game)?"true":"false");
```

**Here is the output**:

```
1Game: true
2Game: true
3Game: false
```

I do not understand why the output when getting to 3Game line  is changed.

Any suggestion on how do  shmget & shmat work?

Comment: Is it deliberate that you attach both pointers to the same shared memory segment?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have many of such lines in the projects. This is an example. Should I use shmget for every variable?

Comment: "Should I use shmget for every variable?" --- who knows, you're overwriting the boolean value with this assignment `*client1 = (client){ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, false};` so it's really not obvious what you're trying to achieve and how the result you get is not what you'd expect.

Comment: You have two pointers pointing to the same location, you write some data to that location, and you are surprised that the data at that location has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shmget()

> shmget() returns the identifier of the System V shared memory segment
>          associated with the value of the argument key.

shmat()

> shmat() attaches the shared memory segment identified by shmid to the
>   address space of the calling process.

basically `shmget` creates a shared memory buffer `IPC_CREAT` and returns it's ID. `shmat` attaches the memory buffer to your application and returns a pointer to it.

since both `game` and `client1` use `shmat` to the same shared buffer, the corrosponding pointer is the same.

considering this:

```
*game = true;
*client1 = (client){ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, false};
```

both lines set values to the same location in memory - hence the result you got is as expected

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html

https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I use separate buffers for every variable and it works.